# How to print middle column with diffrent sting

Tags: unix

Below is a sample:

```
Pid            Name of TTL           TOTAL
-----          ----------------      -------
P36572         TTL rice sum          TOTAL3

P35621         TTL oil type sum      ToTAL6

P35612         TTL type of sausage   TOTAL7
```

I am looking for output in below format in different file of UNIX.

```
Name of TTL     
----------------
TTL rice sum

TTL oil type sum

TTL type of suasage
```

I need help to finish this.

Comment: I've reformatted your sample files in what seemed like the format you intended - but please do edit them again if this edit does not reflect your data.

Comment: Do your `Pid` and `TOTAL` columns always follow the pattern in the sample; in other words: do they ever contain whitespace? Do you perhaps even control the input format and you could separate the columns by tab characters?